# Reload and evil-reload in uwsgi config

Tags: uwsgi

What is the difference between **reload-on-as** and **evil-reload-on-as** options in uwsgi config?
I use **reload-on-as** and uwsgi worker still consumes unlimited memory and reloads when task is finished. I need to kill worker when it consumes limited memory for debug purposes. What is the best way to do it? May be **limit-as** option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

evil-reload-* destroy a worker even if in the middle of a request, while the other one wait for request completion

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear how it should work, but it doesn't work for me (uwsgi-python). Workers still can consume unlimited memory with evil-reload-*.